# Mootools .setStyle doesn't change background color in IE9

Tags: css, background, internet-explorer-9, mootools

I have a MooTools script, which handles panel with buttons (switching the panel content).

Here is the script - every button sets corresponding panel visible + change a background of itself:

```
buttons.addEvent('mouseenter', function(button){
        var panel = 'panel-' + this.get("id");
        $$('.panel').setStyle('display','none');
        $(panel).setStyle('display','block');
        buttons.setStyle('background',null);
        this.setStyle('background','#183c7c');
    });
```

For IE (tried in 8 and 9), the last row of the script does not work - the background of button itself is not changed. For Firefox and Chrome it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working for me under IE9: http://jsfiddle.net/EWUeP/

html:

```
<div id="divy"></div>
```

css:

```
div{
    width:300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #eee000;
}
```

js:

```
var d = document.id('divy');
d.setStyle('background','#183c7c');
```

But nevertheless if you want only to change bg color - call the correct css: `d.setStyle('background-color','red');` background rule is the global rule for all background css types [color url position repeat etc..]

Comment: Forgot to mention - I have tried background-color too, but it was causing troubles also in Chrome then. Could it be, that some other CSS (not those added by script) are affecting the style? Could you maybe have a look at joomla.zdenekvanek.cz? You can see the panel dirrectly on homepage. It works in FF and CHrome, not in IE8 and 9.

Comment: Yep - I see what happens - in IE you have the filter rule in those css which override the background color. You need to play with this filter on-off when you hovering